# Flexdashboard sidebar that can be toggled

Tags: r, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I am using R flexdashboard and would like to create a left sidebar menu that can be toggled just like in this Shinny app dashboard [example](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/087-crandash/) ([source](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/main/087-crandash/ui.R)).

[image]

There is an option to create a sidebar menu with the flexdashboard ([see](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/articles/layouts.html#input-sidebar-global)), but it is static.

[image]

If there is not a building option to do so, could it be done via css or jquery for instance? An other option could be a sidebar that expands on hover.